# Understanding a connection in my circuit design on a virtual breadboard of a voltage regulator

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, voltage-regulator, parallel, breadboard

[image: Circuit-1]

Circuit-1 is a simulation of a breadboard with 2 capacitors connected in parallel with a voltage regulator.

[image: Circuit-2]

Circuit-2 is also a simulation of a breadboard with 2 capacitors connected in parallel with the voltage regulator but the way of connecting the components differ.

Both ways work on the simulation but can someone tell me which circuit connection is correct and why?

Comment: In a typical xx7805 regulator circuit the small input cap is more important especially if the input power leads are long.  The small output cap is not always needed but can be helpful for a high speed response.  On an actual PCB these caps should be placed very close to the regulator pins.

Answer (score 2):

If you draw the schematics, they are identical, so schematic-wise, there is no difference and both are equally correct.

However, the physical routes between components are different in the different implementations of the circuit.

Since this is a breadboard implementation, so this is not a great high speed design anyway, and the wiring between components is not that great for high speed design either, it really does not make much difference which breadboard wiring of the two you use, they are both approximately equal.

Comment: what do i need to do  in order to have a high speed design?

Comment: @Lashca_Pieterse The first step is to not use a breadboard.

Answer (score 0):

Both are actually the same circuit.

Any component pins that are connected by wires form a so-called "net"; it doesn't matter how and in what order they're connected together. If there's a path through only wires between two component legs, they're connected.

In the first picture, the red wires on the left half of the breadboard form a net connecting the diode's cathode, positive leg of the electrolytic capacitor, one leg of the ceramic capacitor, and input of the voltage regulator.

In the second picture, the red wires form a net that connects the exact same legs of the exact same components, and hence the circuit is identical.

As Justme mentioned in the comments, this only holds for circuits that only operate under such conditions that wire parasitics (resistance, inductance, capacitance) are insignificant.

Comment: The ceramic polarity is exactly the same. And while the schematic is identical for both wirings, the circuit wiring is different. However in real life with real circuits, it does matter how you route the currents between components and how long the routes are. These both will work and are approximately equal, but both would be pretty poor if this was a PCB and powering high speed digital logic.